# PHP Arrays - getting multi-dimensional values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following Array data:

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> array(8) { 
      [0]=> string(2) "55" 
      [1]=> string(1) "2" 
      [2]=> string(1) "1" 
      [3]=> string(1) "3"  
      [4]=> string(1) "4" 
      [5]=> string(1) "5" 
      [6]=> string(1) "6" 
      [7]=> string(1) "7" 
      } 
    }
```

I'd like to be able to bring back the values, individually for `[1]` and `[2]` for examples, who's values are 2 and 1 respectively.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Can you give us sample output?

Comment: Loop twice. =) =) (**Nesting**).

Comment: Apols everyone, I am having one of those days.  See my own answer below.

Comment: Well, I guess I was entirely on a different path. :|

Comment: No worries @BackinaFlash - again apols!

Comment: The mark downs are fair - but come on - I admitted my mistake!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a multidimensional array, you need to reference the nested array, and then the nested array element.

For example, if your array was set in $array, you would reference it as:

`$array[0][1];`

Which is basically saying 'Value of 2nd element of 1st nested array'.

Answer (score 2):

$matches[0][1] - cannot believe I actually asked this question.

Comment: I am suitable embarrassed and it's only Monday.